# What is the Ubuntu installation going to do to my Windows files...?

Tags: 12.10, windows, files

I am installing Ubuntu 12.10 in Windows with Wubi and I want to know if it's going to COPY my Windows files and place them in Ubuntu, or MOVE them to Ubuntu, or leave the Windows files so I start with an empty Ubuntu (which I want). Can someone please tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will leave the Windows files alone and create a place for Ubuntu to run out of.  WUBI installs Ubuntu as an application inside of Windows.

Comment: So the Ubuntu installation will only have the default programs it comes with?

Comment: Yes. Unless you choose to install other programs during or after the install process.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Also, do you think I will need to back up my files? I'm not sure if Wubi is that safe...

Comment: I can't comment on the stability of wubi but it is always a good idea to back up your files no matter what. Backing up is too easy to not do. Also I would appreciate it if you marked this as the answer if you are happy with it. :)

Comment: Ok, I was going to back up my files just in case :) Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That's up to you. Ubuntu can be installed besides Windows. So you have a multi-boot system and no files are touched. Of course, you need enough space for doing this.
The other option is to wipe all the data and install Ubuntu over your system, so every file on your system partition are lost.

My Advise: Backup all files you want to keep.

Comment: I'm installing it inside Windows 7 with Wubi, so I'm not replacing my OS. My Windows installation will stay exactly how it would be if I didn't install Ubuntu, right?

Comment: Yes, if u just use Wubi to test Ubuntu nothing will happen to your files.

Comment: Test Ubuntu? Wat do you mean by test? I thought there was only one way to use Wubi to install Ubuntu.